# What is most beneficial to use? $(this) vs. this

Tags: jquery

When is it most beneficial to use `$(this)` and when should I use the plain old `this` (`$(this)[0]`)?

I have posted on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) before, where someone told me I shouldn't use `$(this)` so much in my function but rather `this`.

Why? Is `$(this)` rather memory intensive or something? Or does it sometimes contain more data than you are currently using in your function (too much overhead)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you need. In the context of e.g. an event handler,

- `this` is a reference to the native DOM object
- `$(this)` is a reference to the jQuery extended object which adds all the jQuery goodness to an element (`.css()`, `.attr()` and the dozens, if not hundreds of additional methods).

In a jQuery extended object, the native DOM object is still available as the `0` property:

```
element = $("#element");
alert(element[0].id); // Outputs the native object's `id` property
```

If you need only the native functionality, there is no need to wrap it into a jQuery object, but you usually want to be able to access the extended functions at some point.

Re overhead, I don't have any hard data but I imagine this is one of the most heavily optimized operations in all of jQuery, as it often has to be applied to every element. Unless you're working with tens of thousands of elements, there is probably not going to be a notable difference either way.

Comment: Well, then it really doesn't matter which one you use, right? Would it be better to store `$(this)` in a variable, and then use the variable all the way through your function: `var element = $(this);`

Comment: @Anriëtte Combrink: It does matter. E.g. to access the ID of an element, you can do `this.id`, but not `$(this).id`.

Comment: @Anriëtte if you want to work with `$(this)`, you would usually store $(this) in a variable and work with that from there on.

Comment: For longer functions, I would store the jQuery wrapped objects in variables as you suggest. Also, as a convention, I start them with a `$`, so `var $element = $(this)`.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, I understand that, I just meant in terms of overhead.

Comment: So, what precisely is the benefit of storing the `$(this)` jQuery object in a variable? They will both, in effect, reference the same object in memory? I don't understand that quite right, I think.

Comment: @Anriëtte it saves the need to call the `jQuery()` function over and over. I assume it doesn't really matter performance-wise as the function is likely to return the same object on multiple calls, but it's a relatively widespread practice. (And it arguably makes the code prettier - every pair of brackets saved is good for the environment!)

Comment: Regarding overhead. The jQuery function can be found [here in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L76). In line 90, the jQuery object is returned if it is a DOM node. So pretty much at the beginning of the function and nothing computational expensive is done.

Comment: Ok, so in actual fact, the need to assign `$(this)` to a variable is actually used to save on brackets and make your script's file size smaller [i.e. the physical overhead of a gazillion ( and/or ) ]. Now that makes sense. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are refering to is using `this` in a jQuery call back function.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    this; // <-- is the DOMElement for a 'A' tag
});
```

You should use `$(this)` when you need to, i.e. when you need to run some form of jQuery method on the selected element.

Note you can retain a reference to the jQuery object for `this` to save recreating it alot:

```
// instead of
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).thatPlugin();
    $(this).find("other").blat();        
    $(this).find("foo").blat();
    // 20 more 
});

// do:
$('a').each(function(){
    var $self = $(this); // keep a reference
    $self.thatPlugin();
    $self.find("other").blat();
    $self.find("foo").blat();
    // 20 more reusing $self
});
```

The naming of `$self` is purely personal preference.